# $x=argmin_{x\in A}||y-x||_2$ iff $\langle y-x,z-x\rangle \leq0$ for all $z\in A$

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider $x\in A\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ with A closed and convex. How can you see that

$$x=argmin_{x\in A}||y-x||_2$$
iff 
$$\langle y-x,z-x\rangle \leq0$$ 
for all $z\in A$.

I tried using parallelogram equality etc. But I still can't see how this works out. Maybe someone has a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is convex, for all $x,z\in A$, $\theta \in [0,1]$, $x + \theta(z-x) \in A$

$$
\|y - (x + \theta(z-x))\|^2 = \|y - x\|^2 - 2\theta \langle y-x,z-x\rangle + \theta^2\|z-x\|^2
$$

So if $\langle y-x,z-x\rangle \le 0$ for all $z\in A$, take $\theta=1$ in the above equation to show $\|y-z\|^2 \ge \|y - x\|^2$.

On the other hand, if for some $z\in A$ we have $\langle y-x,z-x\rangle > 0$, for sufficiently small $\theta$ we have $\|y - (x + \theta(z-x))\|^2 < \|y - x\|^2$.